# aggregator spring cloud stream with timeout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, google-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-stream

I want to make an application that receives messages, stores those messages in a list, and later with and schedule releases those messages every x amount of time.
I know spring cloud stream has an aggregator that already does this, but I think I need it to be done manually because I need to keep a unique message based upon a key and only replace the old message if it matches a specific condition ( I think of it as a Set aggregator with conditions)
what I have tried so far.
also in this link https://github.com/chalimbu/AggregatorQuestionStack

Processor.

```
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Processor
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled


@EnableBinding(Processor::class)
class SetAggregatorProcessor(val storageService: StorageService) {
@Input
public fun inputMessage(input: Map<String,Any>){
    storageService.messages.add(input)
}

@Output
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 20000)
public fun produceOutput():List<Map<String,Any>>{
    val message= storageService.messages
    storageService.messages.clear()
    return message;
}
}
```

Memory storage.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class StorageService {
public var messages: MutableList<Map<String,Any>> = mutableListOf()
}
```

This code generates the following error when I start pushing messages.
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has    no subscribers
at      org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]

The idea is to deploy this app as part of the spring cloud stream (dataflow) platform.

I prefer the declarative approach(over the functional approach), but if somebody knows how to do it with the reactor way, I could settle for it.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to this example(https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/main/processor-samples/sensor-average-reactive-kafka/src/main/java/sample/sensor/average/SensorAverageProcessorApplication.java) I was able to figure something out using flux in case someone else needs it

```
@Configuration
class SetAggregatorProcessor : Function<Flux<Map<String, Any>>,   Flux<MutableList<Map<String, Any>>>> {

override fun apply(data: Flux<Map<String, Any>>):Flux<MutableList<Map<String, Any>>> {
    return data.window(Duration.ofSeconds(20)).flatMap { window: Flux<Map<String, Any>> ->
       this.aggregateList(window)

    }
}

private fun aggregateList(group: Flux<Map<String, Any>>): Mono<MutableList<Map<String, Any>>>? {
    return group.reduce(
        mutableListOf(),
        BiFunction<MutableList<Map<String, Any>>, Map<String, Any>, MutableList<Map<String, Any>>> {
                acumulator: MutableList<Map<String, Any>>, element: Map<String, Any> ->
            acumulator.add(element)
            acumulator
        }
    )
}
}
```

update https://github.com/chalimbu/AggregatorQuestionStack/tree/main/src/main/kotlin/com/project/co/SetAggregator